# LinkedList creating nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list

I tried to implement C++ singly linked. I have created a method which creates a node and add a value and points to another node but i have to remember index.

- How to improve the code and create nodes without remembering index?  (I want to maintain order = first created node points to another etc.)

Class method:

```
void LinkedList::addValue ( int val )
{
    if ( ! index ) 
    {
      n = new Node();
      head = n;
      n->value = val;
      n->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      n->next = new Node( );
      n = n->next;
      n->value = val;
    }

  ++index;
}
```

Comment: Put a `Node* head;` member variable into your `LinkkedList` class. Initialize `head` with `nullptr`. Check `head` against `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another pointer called *Tail* to point to the last element. That way you can add value to the list without the index.
I call this method *append*
void append(int val){

```
 void append(int val) {
        Node* tmp = new Node(); // creating a temporary pointer to a new node
        tmp -> value = val
        last -> next = tmp; // connect the new node to the linked list
        last = tmp;  // set the last to the newly created node
        listSize++; // increase the size of the list
    }
```

You can also improve the code by making a Constructor for the node:

```
Class Node{
public:
    int value;
    Node * next;
    Node(Node * nextEle = NULL) {
        next = nextEle;
    }
    Node(int val,Node * nextEle = NULL) {
        value = val;
        next = nextEle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you already have two member variables: *head* which is the root node and *n* which is the last node. You should initialize both of them with NULL (nullptr for c++11) in constructor. Then you can just check if *n==NULL* when you add a new value to the list.

```
LinkedList::LinkedList():head(NULL),n(NULL)
{}

void LinkedList::addValue ( int val )
{
    if (n==NULL) 
    {
      n = new Node();
      head = n;
      n->value = val;
      n->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
      n->next = new Node( );
      n = n->next;
      n->value = val;
    }
}
```

The index variable, however, can be useful if you want to find the list size in one fast read operation without iterating over all its nodes.